# Show the maximum number of linearly independent $n$-vectors is $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

> Show the maximum number of $n$-vectors that can be linearly independent is $n$.

$n$ referring to the order of the vector, take $n$ linearly independent $n$-vectors. Take any other vector. It's possible to write the vector as a linear combination of the $n$ linearly independent vectors, so $v_{n+1}=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n$. Then we have $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n-v_{n+1}=0$ and the vectors are linearly dependent. Thus $n$ is the maximum number of linearly independent $n$-vectors.

I apologize if this is trivial, but I wanted to verify it nonetheless.

Comment: The logic is valid. You are leaning heavily on the assertion that you can form any vector as a linear combination of any $n$ linearly independent vectors (this is where the more complex logic lies), and essentially proving the more elementary implication that if $v \in \operatorname{span} S$ then $S \cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent. I don't know if this is your intention or not though.

Comment: One other implicit step is that any subset of a linearly independent set is itself linearly independent; that's what allows one to reduce the problem to starting with an $n$-element linearly independent set and showing that it can't be extended to an $(n+1)$-element linearly independent set.